# Loading shared library dynamically using dlopen

Tags: c++, dlopen, dynamic-loading, dlsym

I'm trying to load TestCode.so using dlopen. getNumber() is the function I want to use from the TestCode.so. But when I'm loading the .so. I'm not able to use the function. Its giving the segmentation fault.

Example program:
TestHeader.hpp

```
#ifndef _HEADER_HPP
#define _HEADER_HPP

typedef struct
{
        int number;
} Test;

#endif
```

TestCode.cpp

```
#include "TestHeader.hpp"

extern "C" void getNumber( Test* tObj, int number)
{
        tObj->number = number;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "TestHeader.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
        using std::cout;
        using std::cerr;
        Test* tMainObj = NULL;    
        typedef int (*TestNumber)(Test*, int);

        void* thandle = dlopen("./TestCode.so", RTLD_LAZY);
        if (!thandle) {
                cerr << "Cannot load TestCode: " << dlerror() << '\n';
                return 1;
        }

        // reset errors
        dlerror();

        // load the symbols
        TestNumber getAge = (TestNumber) dlsym(thandle, "getNumber");
        const char* dlsym_error = dlerror();
        if (dlsym_error) {
                cerr << "Cannot load symbol getNumber: " << dlsym_error << '\n';
                return 1;
        }
        printf("Getting my age\n");
        int myAge = 25; 
        getAge(tMainObj,myAge);
        printf("My age from the so is: %d\n",tMainObj->number);

        dlclose(thandle);
}
```

Output:

> Getting my age Segmentation fault (core dumped)

For Compilation and creating shared library. I used following command,

```
g++ -fPIC -c -Wall TestHeader.hpp
g++ -fPIC -c -Wall TestCode.cpp 
g++ -shared TestCode.o -o TestCode.so
g++ -fPIC -c -Wall main.cpp
g++ main.cpp -o main TestCode.o -ldl
```

Can anyone help me out understanding this part? Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the segfault? how did you compile the lib and your code (which compiler, flags etc...)?

Comment: Why does your typedef return an `int` but the function `void`?

Comment: @OznOg, I've added in the question

Comment: @Quimby, Thanks for noticing. I've corrected that still getting seg fault in line tObj->number = number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that you never allocate any `Test` object. The pointer is `NULL`(use `nullptr`), so
`tObj->number = number;` is UB and likely a segfault.
There's no reason for `test` to be a pointer.

`Test tMainObj;getAge(&tMainObj,myAge);` is simpler and gets the job done.

Comment: @EmmaRoberts If you want, you can accept this answer, so the question is marked as answered.