# dlopen succeeds (or at least seems to) but then dlsym fails to retrieve a symbol from a shared library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, lazy-loading, dynamic-loading

In an attempt to undersand how lazily loaded dynamic libraries work, I've made up the following (unfortunately non-working) example.

**`dynamic.hpp` - Header of the library**

```cpp
#pragma once

void foo();
```

**`dynamic.cpp` - Implementation of the library**

```cpp
#include "dynamic.hpp"

#include <iostream>

void foo() {
    std::cout << "Hello world, dynamic library speaking" << std::endl;
}
```

**`main.cpp` - `main` function that wants to use the library** (edited from the snippet in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56747328/loading-shared-library-dynamically-using-dlopen))

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

#include "dynamic.hpp"

int main() {
    void * lib = dlopen("./libdynamic.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!lib) {
        std::cerr << "Error (when loading the lib): " << dlerror() << std::endl;
    }
    dlerror();
    auto foo = dlsym(lib, "foo");
    auto error = dlerror();
    if (error) {
        std::cerr << "Error (when loading the symbol `foo`): " << error << std::endl;
    }
    dlerror();

    using Foo = void (*)();
    (Foo(foo)());
}
```

**Compilation and linking**¹

```bash
# compile main.cpp
g++ -g -O0 -c main.cpp
# compile dynamic.cpp into shared library
g++ -fPIC -Wall -g -O0 -pedantic -shared -std=c++20 dynamic.cpp -o libdynamic.so
# link
g++ -Wall -g -pedantic -L. -ldynamic main.o -o main
```

**Run**

```bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH='.' ./main
```

**Error**

```
Error (when loading the symbol `foo`): ./libdynamic.so: undefined symbol: foo
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As far as I can tell, the error above clearly shows that the library is correctly loaded, but it's the retrieval of the symbol which fails for some reason.

---

(¹) A few options are redundant or, at least, not necessary. I don't think this really affects what's happening, but if you think so, I can try again with the options you suggest.

Comment: You haven't declared `foo` with C linkage, so it has C++ linkage and its name will be mangled accordingly. Either use C linkage or give `dlsym` the mangled name according to the ABI.

Comment: Consider running `nm` on the .so to see what symbols are actually present.

Comment: @user17732522, I see that the former solution consists in just prepending `extern "C"` to the function declaration in the `dynamic.hpp` header. I wonder what the drawbacks of this solution (as compared to the latter of using the mangled name) are. Would you mind posting the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auto foo = dlsym(lib, "foo");
```

Perform the following simple thought experiment: in C++ you can have overloaded functions:

```
void foo();

void foo(int bar);
```

So, if your shared library has these two functions, which one would you expect to get from a simple "`dlsym(lib, "foo")`" and why that one, exactly?

If you ponder and wrap your brain around this simple question you will reach the inescapable conclusion that you must be missing something fundamental. And you are: name mangling.

The actual symbol names used for functions in C++ code are "mangled". That is, if you use `objdump` and/or `nm` tools to dump the actual symbols in the shared libraries you will see a bunch of convoluted symbols, with "foo" hiding somewhere in the middle of them.

The mangling is used to encode the "signature" of a function: its name and the type of its parameters, so that different overloads of "foo" produce distinct and unique symbol names.

You need to feed the mangled name into `dlsym` in order to resolve the symbol.

Comment: Although this is the right diagnosis, the remedy is not portable because name mangling is dependent on compiler version, etc.  I would instead recommend changing the declaration to `extern "C" void foo();` in order to ensure the symbol name is simply `foo`.  That is what was done in the question the OP linked to and was trying to emulate.